# Why my IPV6 gets truncated when stored?

Tags: mysql, ipv6

I have MySQL column to store IP, the data type is `varbinary 16`.

When I save IPV6 into it, why is it truncated?

```
2001:11ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Becomes:

```
2001:11ff:ffff:f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to store string representation of your IPv6 address in your `VARBINARY(16)` column. You should convert it to `VARBINARY(16)` using function [INET6_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton), and then you can retrieve it back using [INET6_NTOA()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-ntoa).

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7354d/1).

Comment: what data type should i store if i want store it in string, my Mysql is 5.5 dont have INET6

Comment: You should use `VARBINARY(16)` type. However, functions `INET6_NTOA()` `INET6_ATON()` were added only in MySQL 5.6.3. You can either upgrade to 5.6, or convert it on client.

Comment: my share hosting is 5.5 :(

Comment: You can still create your own implementation on client side. Biggest challenge would be to use BLOB binding of your data to VARBINARY column - you will have to use prepared statements and custom binding type.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6.3 has support for IPv6 addresses, see the following: "[INET6_ATON(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton)".